# Icefaces: How to use OnLoad

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm new to [Icefaces](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/). I want to know how to use onload method, or I want to call some methods when the page is loading.

Comment: What have you got working so far?  Please post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSF page:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView"
        listener="#{yourManagedBean.yourMethod()}" />
```

In YourManagedBean.java:

```
public void yourMethod() {
   ...
}
```